# WriteFile Failure with error code 87 in 4096 Bytes per sector Disk

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, disk, hard-drive

WriteFile() Win32 call with input buffer size = 512 Fails., when i try to write to the disk that has bytes per sector = 4096.[3 TB disk]. Same WriteFile with input buffer size = 4096 works fine.,

Can any body explain this behavior.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Not all Windows supports 4K sector size.

Comment: 87L ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER The parameter is incorrect

Comment: Tell us more about what type of handle you are writing to. We need more details. Don't be shy!

Comment: are you opening this file with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

For low-level I/O operations, your buffer must be an integer multiple of the sector size. In your case, `k*4096`. Most likely your hard drive wasn't manufactured a long time ago. They are called "Advanced Format" and have 4096 bytes per sector. Mine doesn't mind if I set it to 512 because it's old. Try using the `GetDiskFreeSpace` function to learn more about your hard-drive.